# routing to a new page from navbar with react routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make a 2nd page for my website and I'm having hard time understanding how react routing works .

Here's the code:

```
import { FaGithub, FaUserAstronaut, FaLinkedin } from 'react-icons/fa';
import MarsSvg from './MarsSvg';
import MarsPage from '../pages/MarsPage'; 
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"



function NavBar () {
  return (
    <nav className=''>
      <div className="flex justify-around items-center text-5xl">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/mars" element={<MarsPage />} />
        </Routes>
 
        <MarsSvg/>
        <ul className='flex  hover:scale-125 hover:bg-white duration-500 rounded-full'>
          <a href='https://github.com/DevSnippy'>
            <FaGithub/>
          </a>
        </ul>

        <ul className='flex  hover:scale-125 hover:bg-white duration-500 rounded-full'>
          <FaUserAstronaut/>
        </ul>

        <ul className='flex  hover:scale-125 hover:bg-white duration-500 rounded-full'>
          <FaLinkedin/>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default NavBar
```

It does render a component but I want 2 things to happen:

- 1st for the user to click an icon to activate the route
- 2nd for it to a new blank page

Comment: Where have you defined your routes?

Comment: Routes component needs to be placed in App component. and NavBar can only have the paths, then Routes would handle it. I think you need to follow a basic how to routes in react

Comment: You need to render the routes you want to match a URL path, typically in the app, and you should render links to them, typically in the navbar. Keep in mind that your app is still *technically* a Single Page App, so if you wanting to open parts of your app in a new window/tab reference, you can't use `react-router-dom` for this, you'll need to use `window.open` and ensure your app can reload any state it persisted to longer-term storage.

Answer (score 0):

I add `BrowserRouter` over the component to get the routes to work (wont work without). Then I used `Link` from react-router-dom to go to a new page upon clicking your svg icon.

(see: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

```
import React from "react";
import { FaGithub, FaUserAstronaut, FaLinkedin } from "react-icons/fa";
import MarsSvg from './MarsSvg';
import MarsPage from '../pages/MarsPage'; 
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <nav className="">
        <div className="flex justify-around items-center text-5xl">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/mars" element={<MarsPage />} />
          </Routes>
          <Link to="/mars">
          <MarsSvg/>
          </Link>
          <ul className="flex  hover:scale-125 hover:bg-white duration-500 rounded-full">
            <a href="https://github.com/DevSnippy">
              <FaGithub />
            </a>
          </ul>
          <ul className="flex  hover:scale-125 hover:bg-white duration-500 rounded-full">
            <FaUserAstronaut />
          </ul>
          <ul className="flex  hover:scale-125 hover:bg-white duration-500 rounded-full">
            <FaLinkedin />
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Is this what you meant?

Edit: Switched incorrect link from v5 to v6

Comment: so something kinda weird happend when i tried your code 

it compiled but didnt show anything on page till I removed the browser router 

when I removed the browser router it worked as intended 

I just want now for it to return an empty page

Comment: i think ill keep studing from here 

tnx for the help tho appreciate it (:

Comment: Do you want something like this? I made browser router logic into a different page. https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-thunder-duu53q?file=/src/Navbar.js

Comment: Since the OP's and your code are both `react-router-dom@6` API you might want to link to the v6 docs instead of the v5 docs.